# Emulator process has terminated

Tags: android, android-emulator

Trying to run Android emulator. Got error:

```
The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_34 has terminated.
```

Wipe data not helps. How to solve this problem?

Content of idea.log

[image]

```
2023-06-13 16:24:02,153 [ 166903]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Android emulator version 32.1.13.0 (build_id 10086546) (CL:N/A)
2023-06-13 16:24:02,153 [ 166903]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Found systemPath C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
2023-06-13 16:24:02,260 [ 167010]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\g\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_34.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2023-06-13 16:24:05,529 [ 170279]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)
2023-06-13 16:24:05,529 [ 170279] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073740940
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code -1073740940
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:184)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorProcessHandler$ConsoleListener.onTextAvailable(EmulatorProcessHandler.kt:89)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:248)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy56.onTextAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTextAvailable(ProcessHandler.java:222)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessTerminatedListener.processTerminated(ProcessTerminatedListener.java:54)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:248)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy56.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.lambda$notifyTerminated$2(ProcessHandler.java:206)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$TasksRunner.execute(ProcessHandler.java:281)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:189)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyProcessTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:185)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(BaseProcessHandler.java:61)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$1.lambda$startNotified$0(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:98)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$0(ProcessWaitFor.java:45)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:212)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$1(ProcessWaitFor.java:23)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-06-13 16:24:05,531 [ 170281] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2  Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
2023-06-13 16:24:05,531 [ 170281] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-06-13 16:24:05,532 [ 170282] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - OS: Windows 11
2023-06-13 16:24:06,242 [ 170992]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_2_API_34 is online, assuming it's not
2023-06-13 16:24:06,242 [ 170992]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 is online, assuming it's not
2023-06-13 16:27:48,353 [ 393103]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_2_API_34 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2023-06-13 16:27:48,379 [ 393129]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Android emulator version 32.1.13.0 (build_id 10086546) (CL:N/A)
2023-06-13 16:27:48,380 [ 393130]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Found systemPath C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
2023-06-13 16:27:48,495 [ 393245]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\g\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_34.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2023-06-13 16:27:51,688 [ 396438]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)
2023-06-13 16:27:52,433 [ 397183]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_2_API_34 is online, assuming it's not
2023-06-13 16:27:52,433 [ 397183]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 is online, assuming it's not
```